# How to enable ACL feature in Redis

Tags: redis

I am getting below error with `ACL` command.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> AUTH password
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> ACL CAT
(error) ERR unknown command `ACL`, with args beginning with: `CAT`,
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Other commands do work properly

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set key value
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get key
"value"
```

Redis version: 6.0.8

```
~ redis-cli --version
redis-cli 6.0.8
~ redis-server --version
Redis server v=6.0.8 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64 build=a133381967338273
```

Is there any specific configuration to enable `ACL` feature?

Comment: Everything works fine when I download the package manually and follow the installation procedure [https://redis.io/download](https://redis.io/download). Not sure why `redis-server` apt package didn't work as expected

Answer (score -4):

Redis was designed to be used in a trusted private network. It supports a very basic security system to protect the connection between the client and server via a plain-text password. Redis does not implement Access Control List (ACL). Therefore, it is not possible to have users with different permission levels.

The authentication feature can be enabled through the configuration requirepass. Choose a complex password of at least 64 characters. The command AUTH authenticates a Redis client.
[Refer this](https://gist.github.com/akotlov/3bb94faf19102fc234a5577d0f7fc330)

Comment: You couldn't be more wrong. Try not to just rely on the first google result you see.